How to Make Sweat Drip Down and Fall Off a Surface in Blender's Geometry Nodes?

I'm working on a project in Blender using Geometry Nodes, and I'm trying to achieve the following effects:
・Make a monkey object (Suzanne) sweat.
・The sweat droplets should move down the surface and fall off at the lowest points (such as the chin or ears).
Currently, I have managed to make droplets (represented by ICO spheres) move along the surface. However, I am struggling with the following issues:
How to detach the droplets from the surface and make them fall once they reach the edge using Geometry Proximity?
Any advice or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Note: I previously asked a related question on Reddit but didn't find a complete solution there.

pls read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and focus on one question. You may open as many questions as you want. thx.

I have revised my question to focus on a single issue as suggested. Thank you for the feedback!

If the point position minus the geometry proximity output position only have a Z component equal to the gravity, it means it is either hanging down the geometry, in this case you can detach it (let it fall and don't set its position to the geometry proximity output), or it is stuck on top of a perfectly flat surface, in which case you can stop the simulation.

I have to say I think the order of operations is reversed in your simulation, the droplets should first search if there is any geometry below them, and roll in the direction of the descending tangent, or stay in place if they are on a flat surface or a local hole, or apply gravity if there is no geometry below it.

Thank you for your response! Could you please provide guidance on how to determine if the point is hanging from the geometry or if there is no geometry below it, as suggested? Your assistance is greatly appreciated!
